# why last sign in IP and current sign in IP Rails Devise not correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using rails occasionally, and first time using devise with trackable, and when i look into my table, the *current_sign_in_ip* and *last_sign_in_ip* are `::1` not my current ip, Cani know why? I already defined on `user.rb` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :trackable
end
```

Comment: What do you mean my your current ip? Seems like you are running the application  locally. `::1` is IPv6 loopback address to which `localhost` resolves to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: ohh I see, if I don't run locally, it would not be like that?? @NitishParkar, I really have no idea about network things :D, but how I can test to make sure it record the  IP? because I want validate :D

Comment: The only test I'd consider *possibly* writing is that the `current_sign_in_ip != nil`. Beyond that, in my opinion it would be pointless to test. You didn't write the code to track the IP address; it's part of the `devise` library -- are you going to write your own tests for every feature of every library you use?? Worry about testing your own code, not other people's.

Comment: He meant testing manually I think, not automated tests. To verify that `devise` is integrated properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Devise to record your public ip, you need to expose your local server to the internet and access it from the outside. The easiest way to achieve that is using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Assuming your rails server is listening on the default port - 3000, you can generate a public URL using ngrok:

```
$ ngrok http 3000
```

And use that URL to access your Rails app and sign in. Devise will record your public ip as your `current_sign_in_ip`.